# How to control left and right volume of audio separately(imagine wearing a headphone) while playing a sound in flutter app?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, volume

I am creating an app in flutter and stuck in a problem.

Problem : "How to control left and right volume of audio separately(imagine wearing a headphone) while playing a sound in flutter app?"
Please redirect me to some specific helpful resource like how can i control the left and right ear volumes by having 2 separate sliders.

Here is my ui, I want left slider to control the volume of my left channel and same with right.

you can also imagine a mixer for recording audio.
Kindly please help.

Thank you.

[image: you can see the ui part here]

Answer (score 0):

For that, you will have to use the android MediaPlayer class. It has a method called setVolume which accepts two parameters (one for right volume scalar and other one for left)